# Am I using the CSS parent > child selector correctly?

Tags: css, css-selectors, parent-child

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="footer">
    <a href="/">Home</a> | 
    <a href="/about">About</a> | 
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

With the following styling:

```
#footer {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: white;
    width: 960px;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000;
}
#footer > a {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Is there any particular reason that the padding isn't applied to all of the child `<a>` elements of my `#footer` div?

I'm trying a similar effect without a `parent > child` selector somewhere else on my page, so I'm assuming it's a problem with my selector.

Browser version: Chrome 11 Beta Mac OS X

Comment: The first thing you need to put down is browser model and version.  Many older versions of IE do not support the immediate-child selector, e.g.  Also, you need to specify what you mean by "not working".

Comment: turn on Chrome's developer tools, point to the <a> tag in question, and check its padding.  There can be millions of reasons why it doesn't show up -- for example, has it been overwritten by a higher-priority rule?

Comment: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/ --- top padding is generally ignored for elements that are `display: inline;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `#footer a:first-child` do it?

-- Answer from the comments below --

Ahh, they're all inline. To define padding separate from the others they need to be "block" elements, floating next to each other?

Adding

```
#footer a { display:block; float:left; }
```

would give you the ability to give the first one padding the other two don't have

Comment: I get the right response using the browser you mentioned. It doesn't seem to discriminate between elements using the '>' though.  http://jsbin.com/oqova4/edit

Comment: I am using node.js if that makes any difference.  Should I post my server and port number?

Comment: I really doubt that would be affecting your CSS. If you can get your design working in jsbin or a standalone HTML file, then it could be nodejs - but to start with I couldn't see how that would affect it. "Apple Alt J" into Dev Tools, and check the styling (as Stephen Chung above mentioned) and check the styling on each element

Comment: Try this (http://jsbin.com/acahe6/3/) rough version of what my page looks like.  By checking the dev tools, I'm getting no padding.  Maybe it is being overwritten.

Comment: Ahh, they're all inline. To define padding separate from the others they need to be "block" elements, floating next to each other?

Comment: OK, so is it possible to remedy this with a `display:block`?

Comment: Adding #footer a { display:block; float:left; } would give you the ability to give the first one padding the other two don't have.... But they look fine inline?

Answer (score 2):

@boss, `<a>` is an inline element not a block element. so, vertically margin & padding only working on block element . Then define `display:block` in your `a` tag  for more information please check this [Why do bottom padding and bottom margins not help to add vertical spacing between these links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134779/why-do-bottom-padding-and-bottom-margins-not-help-to-add-vertical-spacing-between)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why this isn't working, however as a remedy, I recommend wrapping all your links in like a `div` and giving that a `margin-top`. Check out the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/Ft7Tr/

I hope this helps.
Hristo